# Word-wrapping plain-text messages at 72 columns?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, email, stackexchange.com, newsletter

Would it be possible to word wrap the `text/plain` email messages at 72 columns? As is, it's reasonably difficult to read in a plain-text email client. This is what it looks like right now:

```
8 new questions in [postgresql filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/1691/postgresql) on stackexchange.com

[Select Records :Postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846267/select-records-postgresql)
Can you anyone tell me the query for following scenario . I have following column in table access_log customer_id | service_name | accessed_time Lets says customer might have accessed the ...          
Tagged:  sql  query  postgresql   by [pavun_cool](http://stackoverflow.com/users/279372/pavun-cool) on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)                                                     

[It's getting longer to get the last value of my table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845193/its-getting-longer-to-get-the-last-value-of-my-table)                                                 
I have a table, in my Postgres database, that stores values every 10 minutes. I now have a lot of records in that table (I do not want to delete the old ones). Basically, the row contains a value and …
Tagged:  postgresql  datetime  indexing   by [Luc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/231957/luc) on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)
```

Ideally, I'd like to see:

```
8 new questions in [postgresql] on http://stackexchange.com/filters/1691/postgresql

[Select Records :Postgresql]
    Can you anyone tell me the query for following scenario . I have following column
    in table access_log customer_id | service_name | accessed_time Lets says customer
    might have accessed the ...          
Tagged:  sql  query  postgresql   by pavun_cool
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846267/select-records-postgresql


[It's getting longer to get the last value of my table]
    I have a table, in my Postgres database, that stores values every 10 minutes. I
    now have a lot of records in that table (I do not want to delete the old ones).
    Basically, the row contains a value and …
Tagged:  postgresql  datetime  indexing   by Luc
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845193/its-getting-longer-to-get-the-last-value-of-my-table
```

Or something similar where it's easy to read and doesn't rely on my terminal width to be limited to 72 characters for the description to wrap. I also nuked some of the superfluous data that isn't relevant when reading a pure text version.

Comment: Doesn't your terminal have an option to do this automatically, to whatever width your terminal is currently set at?

Comment: Formatting at 72 characters breaks anything wider or narrower than 72 characters. And what @kevin said.

Answer (score 8):

Plain-text newsletter and filter subscription emails now wrap after 72 characters.

To see it in action, check out the [plain-text version of the Stack Overflow Newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=stackoverflow.com&format=text).

Comment: _plain-text version_ looks... gorgeous

Comment: Probably a related bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143295/urls-break-in-text-plain-version-of-emails

Answer (score 6):

I'm not receiving any mails from SE, so my argument might be moot, but...may I say that there are people which do not view their e-mails with a width of 72/80 columns, but less. If hard linebreaks are inserted, it means that the lines get wrapped twice:

```
8 new questions in [postgresql] on http://stackexchange.com/filters/1691/postgresql

[Select Records :Postgresql]
    Can you anyone tell me the query for following scenario . I have
following column
    in table access_log customer_id | service_name | accessed_time Lets
says customer
    might have accessed the ...          
Tagged:  sql  query  postgresql   by pavun_cool
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846267/select-records-postgresql


[It's getting longer to get the last value of my table]
    I have a table, in my Postgres database, that stores values every
10 minutes. I
    now have a lot of records in that table (I do not want to delete
the old ones).
    Basically, the row contains a value and …
Tagged:  postgresql  datetime  indexing   by Luc
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845193/its-getting-longer-to-get-the-last-value-of-my-table
```

Comment: I think you're misusing 'mute', which means silent or inaudible. You want ['moot'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moot), which means *Having no practical impact or relevance*.  Also, it's sounds strange to say 'a little bit moot', especially when you've already qualified with 'might be'.  (Commenting instead of editing for educational purposes.)

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Interesting, I didn't get a notification for that comment...anyway, you're right. I really want to use `moot`. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin / Asylum no, you're both wrong... [it's a *moo* point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLwYpSCrlHU#t=21s)