# Plain text parts in subscription emails now lack links

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, tag-filters

Today, the mails I get through my filter subscriptions changed. The plain text part no longer contain any links. Before it would be Markdown code and start like this:

```
1 new question in [Mercurial filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/28651/mercurial) on stackexchange.com

[How to configure mercurial to deploy website folder only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826473/how-to-configure-mercurial-to-deploy-website-folder-only)
```

(Notice the lack of line breaks, but that's [another matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111186/132106).)

While my client (Gnus) doesn't understand Markdown, it does recognize and highlight the `http://...` links so that I can click on them. Today the mails starts like this:

```
1 new question in Mercurial filter on stackexchange.com

HG abort on permitted file?
```

There's no links to highlight and this makes the plain text part quite useless.

Could this change be reverted?

Comment: +1 for plain text email.

Comment: Sorry about this.. this behavior was accidentally introduced as part of [this fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126580/144066). It'll be fixed shortly.

Comment: @Emmett: no problem, thanks for looking at this so quickly!

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now.

In fact, the entire plain-text version of the filter subscription email received a much needed facelift ([it now wraps at 72 chars!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126984/144066)), so it should be all-around easier to read.

I don't spend much time consuming plain-text emails myself, so please let me know if it can be improved in other ways.

Comment: Looks fine now.  The wrap-on-72-chars is a very nice touch, but OTOH, wrapping long urls makes it less convenient to paste in an editor.

Comment: s/editor/browser/, of course

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that the wrapping cuts right through the URLs. But it's not a problem: everything after the question ID is ignored so it's okay to follow a truncated URL.