# URLs in text email notifications

Tags: bug, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plain text parts in subscription emails now lack links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126638/plain-text-parts-in-subscription-emails-now-lack-links)

The `text/plain` part of notification messages seems to have been broken recently.  In the past, the textual content had the markdown text with the URLs, but now it seems to be sending just the text, and the URLs are nowhere in sight.  (Unless I force my mail client to use the `text/html` part, of course.)

Grepping through my mailbox, this is a change that happened this month, sometime between the 21st and the 23rd.

(Hopefully this is considered a bug and not some plot to abolish text-based email clients.)

Comment: Related: [Plain text parts in subscription emails now lack links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126638) (or possibly duplicate depending on which emails these are)

Comment: Yes, it seems like the same issue -- though for some reason that one is tagged as a `feature-request`...

Comment: Yeah, I retagged the other question since it seems this was indeed unintended behaviour. Also looks like [it should be fixed shortly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126638/plain-text-parts-in-subscription-emails-now-lack-links#comment343854_126638).