# Plain text version of emails does not contain any links

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, notifications, email

I just signed up, a day or two ago, and I've received a notification that there's something in my inbox.  Unfortunately, my email client isn't able to show me a link to my Inbox, or the message, because of the format of the email.

I normally use the email address that I gave when I signed up, just with MailWasher, which is intended to safely preview emails, as plain text, to decide whether or not to open them in a normal HTML email client.

I would be nice if that email contained a link to my inbox, which could be shown in MailWasher.  In order to collect that email in a normal email client, I'd also have to collect or delete all the other emails sent to that address.

I'm not entirely clear what's been done in that email to stop MailWasher seeing the link.  I can see a link to leave feedback, and one to unsubscribe, but not one to check my inbox.

Sure, I can live without one, but those emails would be a lot more useful to me if I could just click a link to go to my Inbox.

Comment: Looks like a bug, the plain text version of the email simply does not contain links.

Comment: To prove it's a bug, here is an old same bug report that was fixed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126638/plain-text-parts-in-subscription-emails-now-lack-links (whatever fix that was applied, it somehow got reverted/overwriten.)

Comment: Thanks.  Since I'm new, here, I'm not sure if it's appropriate to update the old thread, so I'll let someone else decide.

Comment: No, better have it reported again as you did here. Now we just have to wait...

Comment: Note: [also a problem for mod messages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287755/166789). In that case, I'd say it's fairly important users see *all* of the message.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker should be fixed now, according to the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

We've added written out links to the "Unread Email messages" and "Moderator Message" Plaintext emails, so that people at least know where to go.

Formatting in Plaintext emails still has some issues, those should be addressed sometime next year (since right now we're generating them from the HTML Version, and we're in the process of retooling our email system).

Comment: Is this live? Or will it be live in the next build?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It should be live now. Links within the message itself are still subject to stripping, but there's now a plaintext link to the actual message in the email, so people know where they can go to view it.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested it, and it doesn't seem to work? Not for mod messages anyway ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOLVo.png)). It look the same as [the question I reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287755/166789)).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The change is at the very bottom, instead of linking to "respond **here**", the link to the message is appended fully written out. Though it seems that it's not rendering out correctly, checking.

Comment: Ah, right, I understand what you mean. The reason it's rendering wrong is probably because of the link sniffing code in the email client. The [old version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRmyk.png) (new on top, old on bottom) actually looked okay there.

Comment: Yes, two scenarios. Some clients take the Plaintext version, some strip down the HTML version. In the HTML version it's correct, and in either version, the user will have a link.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, so far.  I got an email telling me there were two emails in my Inbox, but the only link I can see in MailWasher (as plain text) is one to unsusbcribe from stackexchange updates.  It says  "If you no longer wish to receive updates daily, you may unsubscribe from this email (http://meta.stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe/inbox/,,,"