# Links don't show up in plain-text email of mod messages

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

I sent a mod message to myself before sending it to the user to check the formatting and such, and noticed missing links in the plain text version:

HTML version:
[image: HTML version]

Plain text version:
[image: Plain text version]

As you can see, the first three links don't show up at all in the text/plain version of the email.

I pasted the links as-is:

```
http://vi.stackexchange.com/...
some text

http://vi.stackexchange.com/...
Some text
```

Looks like this only happens if there is a text description for the link (`[..](http://..)`), as the fourth link as well as a  link to a post's revisions *did* survive intact.

---

By the way, also note how it doesn't add the `>` markers, and just adds that as plain-text.

The input field is in Markdown – why not just use that as-is as the text/plain part of the email?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Plain text should be, well, plain text. How do you expect it to contain links exactly?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, as plain text :-) That is, just the text  `http://vi.stackexchange.com/...` in the body without any modification. The last link in the example actually has that (my email client makes it blue and clickable, but that's entirely optional). Right now, they completely disappear and there's no indication there was ever a link.

Comment: Well, it happens for all emails, not just moderator messages, and reported before.